# How to write a SQL getdate function to conditionally use 1 of a few possible end dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, getdate, sql-date-functions

I work in Mortgage. Once an Underwriter receives a file (marked as "submitted to Underwriting"), that Underwriter can either approve, approve with conditions, or suspend that file. I am trying to find the number of days that it takes the Underwriter to 'decision' a file, but there are 3 possible decision dates that could be populated: approval date, suspended date, or appr w/ conditions date. So based off whichever decision they make, or whichever of these 3 dates are populated in our system, I need to pull the date from "submission" to that date. Here's an example of what I'm needing, but I need help with formulating it:

GetNumOfBusinessDaysExcludingHolidays(SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, ApprovalDate When ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL)

OR

GetNumOfBusinessDaysExcludingHolidays(SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, ApprovedWithConditionsDate When ApprovedWithConditionsDate IS NOT NULL)

OR

GetNumOfBusinessDaysExcludingHolidays(SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, SuspendedDate When SuspendedDate IS NOT NULL)

Comment: I believe it's SQL Server Management Studio and T-SQL. I am using it through a third party BI software called Motivity

Answer (score 2):

Use coalesce - this will return first not null value - if only one of these fields is populated then this will work for you

```
select datediff(dd, SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, coalesce(ApprovedWithConditionsDate , ApprovalDate , SuspendedDate ))
```

Comment: I plugged in the function and it is bringing up an error. I apologize, I am new to SQL and am still trying to learn. This is the expression I entered that is telling me to check the syntax                                                                    select datediff(dd,SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, coalesce(UnderwritingApprovalDate,UnderwritingConditionalApprovalDate,UnderwritingSuspendedDate))

Comment: All it is saying is "Error Validating Expression :: An error occurred while processing the request. Please check the query syntax and try again." I may need to reach out to the third party software i'm running through

Comment: Yeah maybe they don't support that for some reason - works fine directly on SQL Server